# Translate line vertically and calculate intersection on circle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image: funny shapes]

Let's say I have a line extending from the center of the circle at a 45° angle. If I were to translate that line up 212.132 units, how would I calculate the intersection between the translated line and the green circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the centre of your circle is the origin, then the equation for this circle is
$$x^2+y^2\approx565^2\approx319225$$
$$y^2=319225-x^2$$
You have a $45$ degree angle, meaning a slope of $-1$, forming a line of
$$y=-x+212.132$$
Squaring both sides, you get
$$y^2=(-x+212.132)^2$$
Now sub in your circle to equate them.
$$319225-x^2=(-x+212.132)^2$$
$$319225-x^2=x^2-424.264x+45000$$
$$0=2x^2-424.264x-274225$$
Plug into the quadratic formula:
$$x=\frac{424.264\pm\sqrt{180000-4(2)(-274225)}}{2(2)}$$
$$x=\frac{424.264\pm\sqrt{2373800}}{4}$$
$$x=\frac{424.264\pm1540}{4}$$
We're looking for the left side, or negative $x$, so we need the negative.
$$x=\frac{424-1540}{4}=-278.934$$
Plugging that into the line earlier,
$$y=278.934+212.132=491.066$$
$$(x,y)=(-278.934,491.066)$$
with the centre of the circle as the origin. Note that I rounded a lot of these, but you can plug your numbers into the above to get an exact answer.